# Parallax image is visible or not after scrolling

Tags: javascript, testcomplete

In webpage I have an parallax image ie background image using css style they added, after scrolling the page is still that image is visible in the background or not I want to verify

Verify that image is displayed after scrolling the webpage

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.